# SQL Query: Hide items based on column value?

Tags: php, sql, hidden

I am pulling some data from table in a MySQL database. Inside this table is a column called "hidden", by default it is set to 0, but when an item needs to be hidden, it will be set to 1. So I need a code that I can use that will hide all rows if the "hidden" column is set to 1.

Lets say my code is something simple like this:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY name") 
or die(mysql_error());  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
echo $row['name'];
} 
?>
```

Is there a simple code I can add to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `WHERE` clause on it

```
SELECT * 
FROM clients 
WHERE hidden = 0
ORDER BY name
```

The query above will only show items that are not hidden.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! You answered first. It helps me a TON, thanks!

Comment: Strange... they seemed to have just blocked my account from asking any new questions... What?? Wasn't my question valid or something? Weird...

Comment: Thanks! Since I posted the first comment to you, I've been looking for the "accepted" button everywhere, but can't seem to find it :(

Comment: ah, thanx, now I finally know! Thanx again

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE hidden = 0 ORDER BY name");
```

That's probably the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1) if you always want those rows hidden then you don't even have to load them by altering your query.

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE hidden=0 ORDER BY name;
```

2) You can check that value in the while loop.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
   if($row['hidden']==0) echo $row['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current query

```
SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY name
```

retrieves every row in the table. If you want to hide (not retrieve) rows where the value of the `hidden` column is `1` then just add a WHERE clause to check that `hidden` is not equal to `1`.

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE hidden = 0 ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE hidden=0 ORDER BY name") 
or die(mysql_error());  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
echo $row['name'];
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE hidden=0 ORDER BY name");
```

will return only the rows which are not hidden.

Also, if this is a new program you are going to write, use MySqli or PDO instead of the mysql_* functions since they are deprecated. See - http://us.php.net/mysqli and http://us.php.net/pdo